# How do I turn this into a callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm new to Javascript, and callbacks are blowing my mind a little at the moment. How do I turn the teletyperDiologue function into a callback? The main reason is I want the teletyper to finish it's job before the displayOut function finishes. Thank you in advance for your help.

```js
function displayOut() {
 
 // images
 document.getElementById("imgBox").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + db.rooms[roomLoc].roomImg + ")";
 // Diologue box
 diologueBox.innerHTML = ""; // Clear Box
 teleTyperDiologue(db.rooms[roomLoc].description + 
  " The room contains: " +
   (function() {
    let x = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < db.items.length; i++) {
     if (db.items[i].location === roomLoc && db.items[i].hidden === false) {
      x += db.items[i].name + ", "
     }
    }
    x = x.slice(0, x.length -2);
    if (x === "") {
     x = " nothing of special interest";
    }
    return x;
   })()
  + ".");
};


// Teletyper for Diologue Box
function teleTyperDiologue(string) {
 for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   diologueBox.innerHTML += string.slice(i, i + 1);
  }, 5 * i);
 }
}
```

Comment: the teleTyperDiologue function has a timer event, so it will execute always after the displayOut function has finished, you can try "generators" is an es6 type of function that currently isn't supported in today's browser, but you can compile them in babel, typescript transpilers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example:

```
function test(a) { a(); }
function x() { alert('hello'); }
test(x);
```

in your case:

```
function displayOut(callback) {

  // images
  document.getElementById("imgBox").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + db.rooms[roomLoc].roomImg + ")";
  // Diologue box
  diologueBox.innerHTML = ""; // Clear Box
  callback(db.rooms[roomLoc].description + 
    " The room contains: " +
      (function() {
        let x = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < db.items.length; i++) {
          if (db.items[i].location === roomLoc && db.items[i].hidden === false) {
            x += db.items[i].name + ", "
          }
        }
        x = x.slice(0, x.length -2);
        if (x === "") {
          x = " nothing of special interest";
        }
        return x;
      })()
    + ".");
 };

 displayOut(teleTyperDiologue);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass functions around like variables and return them in functions and use them in other functions. So, when you pass a callback function as an argument to another function, you only need to pass the function definition.

See example below.

```js
function displayOut() {
   console.log("Display Out running...");
}

function teleTyperDiologue(stringParam, callback) {
   console.log("Running teleTyper with string param passed of: ", stringParam);
   callback();
}

teleTyperDiologue ("Test string", displayOut);
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I'm having such trouble with this, everything seemed pretty straight forward up until this point.